# SQL Joining 4 Tables

Tags: sql, database, join

I have to deal with an old Database from my company department.
We use this DB for hardware managing assignment and tracking.

I'm about to build up a new fronted in c#, as the current MS Access is getting way to slow for the task.

(I'm translated the names of the tables and rows into English, for better understanding)

- tbl_hardware
- tbl_hardware_assignment
- tbl_accounts
- tbl_typebradmodel (not important for now, and/or self explanatory)

tbl_hardware
contains the columns HW_ID, serialnumber, type,model,brand, etc (othe necessary information of the Hardware)

tbl_hardware_assignment
contains the columns ID, HW_ID (matching with the tbl_hardware.ID), nameID(matching with tbl_accounts.PersID, and since (a int value formated Date [YYYYMMDD] when the entry was created (was not, my idea...))

tbl_account
contains the columns PersID, Login, etc (other internal information)

This is my current SQL Statement

```
SELECT tbl_hardware.HW_ID,
       tbl_hardware.Aktiv,
       tbl_hardware.typebradmodelID,
       tbl_type.tabel AS Type,
       tbl_brand.tabel AS Brand,
       tbl_model.tabel AS Model,
       tbl_accounts.Login,
       tbl_hardware_assignment.since
FROM tbl_hardware
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_typebradmodel ON tbl_hardware.typebradmodelID = tbl_typebradmodel.typebradmodelID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_type ON tbl_typebradmodel.TypID = tbl_type.TypID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_brand ON tbl_typebradmodel.MarkeID = tbl_brand.MarkeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_typebradmodel.ModelID = tbl_model.ModelID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_hardware_assignment ON tbl_hardware.HW_ID = tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_accounts ON tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = tbl_accounts.PersID
WHERE tbl_hardware.Aktiv = 1 AND 
      tbl_hardware.typebradmodelID in 
      (SELECT tbl_typebradmodel.typebradmodelID
       FROM tbl_typebradmodel
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_type ON tbl_typebradmodel.TypID = tbl_type.TypID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_brand ON tbl_typebradmodel.MarkeID = tbl_brand.MarkeID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_typebradmodel.ModelID = tbl_model.ModelID
       WHERE tbl_typebradmodel.MarkeID = 
             (SELECT tbl_brand.MarkeID 
              FROM tbl_brand 
              WHERE tbl_brand.tabel LIKE 'Samsung')
      ) AND 
      tbl_hardware.HW_ID in 
      (SELECT tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID 
       FROM tbl_hardware_assignment, 
            (SELECT MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) AS lastchange,
                    tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID
             FROM tbl_hardware_assignment 
             GROUP BY tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID) lastentry
       WHERE tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = 
             (SELECT tbl_accounts.PersID 
              FROM tbl_accounts 
              WHERE tbl_accounts.Login = 'MY_USERNAME') AND 
             tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID = lastentry.HW_ID AND
             tbl_hardware_assignment.since = lastentry.lastchange
      )
```

RESULT:

```
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER1   20100218
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER2   20100218
10497   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER3   20100810
10498   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER3   20100810
10498   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER4   20100819
10497   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER4   20100819
10497   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   MY_USERNAME 20120601
10498   1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   MY_USERNAME 20120601
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER3   20130502
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER5   20130507
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   USER3   20130619
9778    1   2868    Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM   MY_USERNAME 20130725
```

But I get too many results, AND wrong/multiple user mappings with one hardware.

Any idea where my mistake is?

BTW.: This statement alone returns the correct values

```
SELECT tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID 
FROM tbl_hardware_assignment, 
     (SELECT MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) AS lastchange, 
             tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID
      FROM tbl_hardware_assignment 
      GROUP BY tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID) lastentry
WHERE tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = 
      (SELECT tbl_accounts.PersID 
       FROM tbl_accounts 
       WHERE tbl_accounts.Login = 'MY_USERNAME') AND 
      tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID = lastentry.HW_ID AND 
      tbl_hardware_assignment.since = lastentry.lastchange
```

RESULT:

```
10497   20120601
10498   20120601
11554   20120601
12353   20120601
13665   20120918
13196   20121129
14616   20130701
15073   20130705
9778    20130725
```

*(As I should not port company stuff outside the office, I hope that I didn't mess up any result or SQL statements.)*

**Here are are more example outputs** [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/BC06w8Ks)

Comment: "to many results, AND wrong/multiple user mappings with one hardware" does not describe the problem sufficiently for anyone to really understand what is going on. Can you provide some (small) sample data?

Comment: Sorry, now i have added some results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join subqueries back onto the tables that they are sourced from, and you can JOIN directly onto them.

Rather than JOINING a whole bunch of tabels directly, you could look at forming subqueries that get the correct constituent parts

Something like the following may be what you are after:

```
SELECT tbl_hardware.HW_ID,
       tbl_hardware.Aktiv,
       tbl_hardware.typebradmodelID,
       typebradmodel.Type,
       typebradmodel.Brand,
       typebradmodel.Model,
       lastentry.Login,
       lastentry.since
FROM (SELECT
        tbl_typebradmodel.typebradmodelID,
        tbl_type.tabel AS Type,
        tbl_brand.tabel AS Brand,
        tbl_model.tabel AS Model
    FROM tbl_typebradmodel
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_type ON tbl_typebradmodel.TypID = tbl_type.TypID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_brand ON tbl_typebradmodel.MarkeID = tbl_brand.MarkeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_typebradmodel.ModelID = tbl_model.ModelID
    ) typebradmodel
LEFT JOIN tbl_hardware ON tbl_hardware.typebradmodelID = typebradmodel.typebradmodelID
LEFT JOIN      
    (SELECT 
        MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) AS lastchange, 
        tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID,
        tbl_accounts.Login
    FROM tbl_hardware_assignment
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_accounts ON tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = tbl_accounts.PersID
    GROUP BY tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID,tbl_accounts.Login ) lastentry ON tbl_hardware.HW_ID = lastentry.HW_ID
WHERE tbl_hardware.Aktiv = 1 AND 
    typebradmodel.Brand LIKE 'Samsung' AND
    lastentry.Login = 'MY_USERNAME'
```

**Update**
The critical part here is getting the lastchange subquery correct, i.e. using all the columns that describe the relation between tbl_hardware_assignment and tbl_accounts

```
SELECT 
    MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) AS lastchange, 
    tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID,
    tbl_accounts.Login
FROM tbl_hardware_assignment
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_accounts ON tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = tbl_accounts.PersID
AND MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) = tbl_accounts.lastchange
GROUP BY tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID,tbl_accounts.Login
```

does this get the right ID's? and if it doesn't, are you able to find out what the relation between these two tables should involve?

Comment: Looked prommissing but i am currently not the owner of 9 monitors.

See -> 
[RESULTS](http://pastebin.com/SPMemYna)

The correct result must be 3 (active hardware devices where the Brand is Samsung)

Comment: I was going by the second query that you said returned the correct values. It also looks like you have duplicate entries in tbl_typebradmodel, e.g. 'Monitor 24" TFT Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM' turns up under typebradmodelIDs [11130, 11840, 11841]

Comment: Ohh sorry, this was my mistake. I just selected one additional row here in this result (3rd row). This one is an internal unique sequenced number for every Hardware. (Fun fact: These unique numbers are ahead of the Hardware IDs. I don't know why...). So there are no duplicate entries

Comment: Any other Ideas left how i may solve my problem? I would appreciate everything! (I could provide more some sample output of the tables)

Comment: Updated with some more thoughts.

Comment: I am Sorry but "AND MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.since) = tbl_accounts.lastchange" seems to be wrong, as there is no such column a lastchange in tbl_accounts. Maybe this link can help understand the tables better [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/BC06w8Ks). Only one Hardware is mine (HW_ID 9778)

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in a comment but I've not got the required rep points.

Have you tried changing your joins around?  Looking at the output I'd suggest maybe trying an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I Think i got the basics

This select now returns the correct Values:

```
    SELECT  tbl_hardware_assignment.ID, 
        tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID, 
        tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID, 
        tbl_hardware_assignment.Since,
        tbl_hardware.Knh
FROM tbl_hardware_assignment
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID, MAX(tbl_hardware_assignment.ID) lastchange
            FROM tbl_hardware_assignment
            GROUP BY tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID
            )
SubSelect ON tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID = SubSelect.HW_ID and tbl_hardware_assignment.ID = SubSelect.lastchange
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_hardware ON tbl_hardware_assignment.HW_ID = tbl_hardware.HW_ID
WHERE tbl_hardware_assignment.namenID = (SELECT tbl_accounts.PersID FROM tbl_accounts WHERE tbl_accounts.Login = 'MYUSERNAME')
AND tbl_hardware.Aktiv = 1
ORDER BY tbl_hardware.Knh
```

**RESULT**

```
ID                  HW_ID         namenID     Since        Knh
------------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
37481               9778          4993        20130725    11130
32506               10497         4993        20120601    11840
32507               10498         4993        20120601    11841
32511               11554         4993        20120601    12876
34226               13196         4993        20121129    14491
37099               14616         4993        20130701    15896
```

I think this is the way i wil go one with as the first few results where correct.

Any improvements or thoughts on that?

I got my final Help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

**Thank you all for you help!**

Comment: dammit... Now I have the problem that i wont get any results If there had been no assignment (during creation, or if someone missed it out) when i am searching just after a Model or something other than a user. Any quick ideas how i sort this out?